# Is there any provided footprint for the AS5F18G04SND-10LIN from Alliance Memory?

Tags: pcb-design, footprint

[Documentation link](https://www.alliancememory.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/flash/AllianceMemory_SPI_NAND_Flash_July2020_Rev1.0.pdf)

All I could find in the documentation was a really low resolution (and impossible to read) package outline. I also looked elsewhere for a footprint for that package and the IC itself, but found nothing. If there isn't a provided footprint for this component, how do I design one?

Comment: Pages 49 and 50 have all the information you need.  The package might also be known as a wson-8. How to design a footprint? Which pcb package? There’s plenty of online information for all the popular packages. Nevertheless, if you’re designing a circuit with this device, the footprint should be the least of your challenges.

Comment: @Kartman No, they don't. That is what I was talking about. They only supply package information, not a footprint. Even then, I can't read that, it is too low res. (Yes, I did try zooming in, it did not help) Additionally, I said that I looked, and found nothing that is actually of any use.

Comment: Argue all you like, there is sufficient information to generate a footprint from. Besides, it’s a standard package so you could use a footprint from a Winbond W25G01 or similar serial flash.

Comment: Sure, there might be, but that is literally part of the question I was asking. How do I use the information given to get a footprint? I don't have any kind of professional software. (All I have is KiCAD) I did try looking for a footprint elsewhere, but found none that actually match the package in anything but name.

Comment: The pitch is 1.27mm (50 thou) between pads, pads are 0.4mm sq and the horz width is 8mm. You can make the pads a bit larger and extend them beyond the package if you want to hand solder it easier.

Comment: I just looked at the winbond w25n01 datasheet. They have the pads at 0.4 x 0.5mm. Their package code is ZE and they call it a wson-8. What information are you missing?. p.s I searched for ‘Kicad wson8’ and there looked to be a few hits.

Comment: Okay, that's actually helpful. I couldn't find anything like that when searching. I even tried directly searching for the same thing you did, but found nothing like what you're talking about. Google gives different results for each account. Why they do this, I have no idea.